# Woocommerce Google Product Feed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes, google-shopping

I'm using `WooCommerce` and the `WooCommerce Google` product feed plugin.

Is there anyway to write a function, that would go through all my products, and if the price of the product is under **$25**, it checks off `"hide from feed"` on the product?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This [Facebook product catalog for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/webtoffee-product-feed/) free plugin has the filter to alter the feed data before sending the feed file or before the direct synching to facebook using API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit plugin file: woocommerce_gpf_frontend.php

right before `return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gpf_exclude_product', $excluded, $woocommerce_product->id, $this->feed_format );`

add this line of code:

```
// hide products of $25 and lower, exclude from product feed. 

    if ( $woocommerce_product->get_regular_price() < 25 ){
                $excluded = true;
            }
```

bang bang!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the product filtering functionality of WooCommerce Product Feed Pro plugin for your purpose. Here is the link https://webappick.com/plugin/woocommerce-product-feed-pro/